# equivalent of onclick="update_x(this)" in jquery? (call function)

Tags: javascript, html, function, jquery

I have a function in html:

```
<script>
function update_x(obj) { 
 ...
}
</script>
```

and I call it on click in html with `onclick="update_x(this)"` (inside of `<div class="aaa">`).

How can be the same achieved in jquery? I've tried some stuff, like:

```
$('.aaa').click(update_x);
 });
```

and

```
$('.aaa').click(function () {
    $(this).update_x(1, false);
 });
```

neither won't work...

Comment: `$('.aaa').click(update_x);` works, put it in DOM ready handler or just before body closing tag `</body>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be equivalent:

```
$('.aaa').click(function () {
    update_x(this);
});
```

But you don't need to use that. Just change your function to

```
function update_x(event_obj) { 
    // 'this' will be the clicked object automatically
    // plus, you have further info in the event object
}
$('.aaa').click(update_x);
```

Make sure `$('.aaa').click(update_x)` is called after the element with class "aaa" exists in the DOM. You can wrap that code in a `document.ready` handler, or use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on).

Comment: probably you can mention about document.ready as well. Probably that could be another reason why his first snippet didn't work

Comment: Added a comment about that, but I believe his first snipped didn't work because he was trying to read `obj` instead of `this` inside the listener.

Comment: That 1st solution is exactly what I need in my specific case. It can't be more simple and it works. Thanks bfavaretto :)